# Oracle Select which produce Insert into

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query like

```
SELECT 'Insert INTO FOO(ID,NAME) values ('||id|| ',' ||NAME||');' as query
FROM FOO
```

This is just an example as I can't provide real query example. So, DON'T pay attention how it works just believe that it works as it should.

Question:

If NULL values exists in selected rows it just produces '' in INSERT INTO query. So I am getting an error while trying to execute insert query. How can I force SELECT query to return NULL instead of ''?

**Example:**

I have

```
Insert INTO FOO(ID,NAME) values (12,);
```

I want to have

```
Insert INTO FOO(ID,NAME) values (12,NULL);
```

Comment: Not sure it will work but try `values ('||id|| ',' ||NULLIF(NAME,NULL)||');'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that `NAME` is a string, so it should be surrounded by single quotes.  So, this might be the query you want:

```
SELECT 'Insert INTO FOO(ID,NAME) values (' || id || ', ''' || NAME ||''');' as query
FROM FOO;
```

If the issue is `id`, then you can do:

```
SELECT 'Insert INTO FOO(ID,NAME) values (' || (CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE CAST(id AS VARCHAR2(255)) END) ||
       ', ''' || NAME ||''');' as query
FROM FOO;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT 'Insert INTO FOO(ID,NAME)
values ('||CASE WHEN id = '''' then 'NULL' else id end||','|| CASE WHEN NAME = '''' THEN null else NAME end || ');' as query
FROM FOO
```

Comment: for all columns which type is not VARCHAR: 

a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: Well, I don't know your table structure, only string can be empty string, so use the case only on this columns! @GrigoriyDidorenko